# Transfer login params from iOS to web service

Tags: objective-c, hash, phpass

I currently have a web service whose backend database stores user passwords using [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) under PHP 5.3 —so it's using `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`. I have exposed an API from that server and I want to authenticate users through that API from and iPhone app. The server uses SSL but I want to hash the password before transferring it.

How can I create a phpass compatible hash from objective-c?

Comment: The phpass webpage you refer to also includes a link to a public domain Blowfish C implementation. Including that in your app should solve it. I don't think iOS has native Blowfish support. It does have native SHA1 support, though, so it might be easier to use that instead.

Comment: have you found anything for phpass in objective-c?